# Slow computer/browser performance for testing heavy javascript script

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a javascript/html5 gif editor and i am wondering how can i test in a slower environment. It works great on my pc but since its using heavy javascript and algorithms i need to see if it works smoothly with a less powerful processor.

Comment: If you can't manage a computer with less powerful processor then I think you don't need to worry about it because I'm from Bangladesh and to be honest I can't manage a slow computer then why should you think about it, nobody uses slower computer anymore.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I think you misunderstand the question. and "nobody uses slower computer anymore. " is just naive. Tablets and netbooks for example are new and slow, as are generally: phones.

Comment: Got it, because of atom processors, I was not thinking about handheld devices.

Comment: I think i got my answer, test on my iphone :) if it works on an iphone probably it will work on most of the pcs right?

Comment: @SheikhHeera not necessarily. There are many, many people who don't upgrade their computers because they are "fast enough" or because they can't. In fact I'd say most non-nerds only upgrade a computer when it breaks. +1 for the q keepwalking, be careful as an iphone is still relatively powerful device :)

Comment: @AD7six, right and most users are basically non-nerds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend setting up a virtual machine using [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). You can adjust attributes like processor speed, number of processor cores, and memory. This will help you test your code out in a slower environments.

Comment: @keepwalking Yes, you will need to install Windows on these virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

What an odd request! Usually people want things faster and faster.

- Using a Virtual Machine is a good solve here. It allows you to allocate exactly how powerful the computer is, and might make a very suitable testing environment for you.
- If you want inefficiency, look no further than Internet Explorer. You just need to make sure it supports your HTML5 and your JS.
- Using older versions of some of the more capable browsers might be a good idea too.
- Also, and this is a bit of a hack, opening your program several times in the same browser might be something to look into. It will hog up the RAM, and your processor will be under more stress and will not perform as well as it would in a normal situation.

Just thought I'd throw out every suggestion I could think of :)